# Transaction in RESTful web service with ORMLite

Tags: java, rest, transactions, ormlite

I'm creating RESTful web services using ORMLite framework as ORM.
It is important that some of my services are one transaction - database should rollback if any exception occurrs.

Here is one of methods I've created:

```
@POST
@CONSUMES(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@PRODUCES(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JSONResponeseLogin getJson(LoginRequest request) {

    /* Extract data from request */

    openDBConnection();
    try {
        TransactionManager.callInTransaction(conn, () -> {
            /* Validate user input and store data to database */
        });
    } catch (InvalidDataInRequestException ex) {
        meta.addError(new ServiceError(errorCode));
        logger.info("Error code: "+ errorCode + " " + ServiceErrorCode.textFromErrorCode(errorCode));
        logger.info("Request: " + request.toString());
        logger.catching(ex);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        meta.addError(new ServiceError(errorCode));
        logger.info("Error code: "+ errorCode + " " + ServiceErrorCode.textFromErrorCode(errorCode));
        logger.info("Request: " + request.toString());
        logger.catching(ex);
    } finally {
        closeDBConnection();
    }

    response.setMetaData(meta);
    return response;
}
```

I have several questions:

1. Am I using wrong tool for this job? I would like my whole method be one transaction, but I have a feeling that TransactionManager from ORMLite is not made for that.
2. Every exception which occurs in transaction is wrapped into SQLException (by TransactionManager). I have no way to distinct and / or handle different kind of exceptions. They all get caught in Exception block. How should I approach that?

**EDIT**:
I found a possible workaround.

I could use a single connection instance (obtained from `ConnectionSource.getReadWriteConnection())` during lifetime of whole REST method.
I can set auto-commit to false on said connection and do manual rollback if exception gets thrown.

Problem is that my `DAO` objects are using `JdbcPooledConnectionSource` for their initialization.

The only question which occurs to me is this safe to do on server which will get ~10-20 requests per second - there must be a reason `DAO` are accepting whole pool?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I using wrong tool for this job? I would like my whole method be one transaction, but I have a feeling that `TransactionManager` from ORMLite is not made for that.

No, it is.  In your "possible workaround" section, that is exactly what the `TransactionManager` is doing:

- Get a single connection.
- Stop auto-commit.
- Start a transaction.
- Do the DB work.
- Stop and commit transaction.
- Restore auto-commit.

> Every exception which occurs in transaction is wrapped into SQLException (by `TransactionManager`).

Right.  The `TransactionManager` needs to catch the exceptions so it can rollback the transaction but I didn't want to throw `Exception` from the methods.

You could catch `SQLException` and then examine the `e.getCause()` output by hand.  A bit crufty but necessary if you want to look at the exceptions.

> Is this safe to do on server which will get ~10-20 requests per second - there must be a reason DAO are accepting whole pool?

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by safe.   I assume that Android can handle having 10-20 open database connections at once.  That's more a question for Android/Sqlite then ORMLite.  This of course assumes that it takes less than a second for your db jobs to finish.